# Allocation tracer which works with Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, memory, profiling, ruby-1.9

There are a number of tools which make it possible to measure how much memory (and how many objects) are allocated by a Ruby program, and where the allocation is occurring.

- memprof
- BleakHouse
- ruby-prof
- (if using JRuby) hprof (and the like)

Unfortunately, it seems like all these tools only work with Ruby 1.8, at least for now. Even JRuby is only Ruby 1.8-compatible right now. Is there a good allocation tracer out there which works with Ruby 1.9?

Comment: What did you mean by JRuby being only 1.8 compatible? I thought it's been 1.9 compatible for a while.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, last time I worked with JRuby (which was quite a while ago now) it was compatible with MRI 1.8. If you'd like to edit this question to make it more useful for new readers, please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `perftools.rb` (https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb) can collect information on object allocations, and it works with Ruby 1.9. Unfortunately, it segfaults when I try to use it to trace object allocations!

If the problem is fixed, I will edit this answer.